# Password Input disappearing on React Re-Render

Tags: reactjs, tags

So I have some simple JSX

```
<div className="rPasswordDisplayToggle">
    {showPs ?
        <i class="fas fa-eye" onClick={() => setShowPs(false)}></i> :
        <i class="fas fa-eye-slash" onClick={() => setShowPs(true)}></i>}
</div>
<div className="rWrapper" ref={passwordRef}>
    <div className="rName">
        <p className="rNameBouncerVariation2">What do you want your Password to be ?</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type={showPs ? "text" : "password"} className="rNameInputNoAnim" placeholder="Your Password..."></input>
    </div>
    <br />
    <button className="rBackButton" onClick={() => changeFormState(5, true)}>
        <i className="fas fa-arrow-left" style={{ marginRight: "10px" }}></i> Back
    </button>
    <button className="rNextButtonWMargin" onClick={() => changeFormState(7, false)}>
        Next   <i class="fas fa-arrow-right rNameIcon"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

I have a simple state called showPs defined as `const [showPs, setShowPs] = useState(false);`
Nothing Too Big.

But when I press the button and the React page re-renders, the password input disappears.I tried using the `value` prop and another state, but it still didn't work.I do not know why, in other projects this never was a problem, but this has cropped up from nowhere.BTW, I recorded a video showcasing my problem at https://github.com/LAKSHYAJAIN16/assets/blob/main/stackoverflow.mp4. Idduno if the video will help, but I recorded it anyways.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Set value and onChange for the input  <input type={showPs ? "text" : "password"} className="rNameInputNoAnim" value={somethingfromstate} onChange={handler} placeholder="Your Password...">

Comment: @RanganathMD than it gets even worse : everytime the  value Updates it removes the focus and I have to click on the input field again

Comment: It must be because in some cases or for some time the component is unmounting and mounting as a new one. show us the full code inside this component